# How do I plot a mean value in a ggplot2 line plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset that is Weights taken on 4 separate dates. The weights belong to 4 different grouping A, B, C, D. I need to graph the average of the weight of each group on each specific day as 4 separate line graphs on one axis. Can anyone help?

[image: This is the picture of what I have done so far for one group]

Comment: Please don't show data as a screenshot. Make your question reproducible by (1) including data in a copy&paste-able format using `dput`, (2) include your code attempt, and (3) include your expected output for the sample data you give.

Answer (score 1):

Let's make up some data:

```
set.seed(111)
mydata <- tibble(Group = rep(LETTERS[1:4], each = 4), 
                 Date = as.Date(rep(c("2018-01-01", "2018-02-01", "2018-03-01", "2018-04-01"), 4)), 
                 Weight = sample(50:100, 16, replace = TRUE))
```

You can easily plot the mean by group using `stat_summary`. Using your definition *"the average of the weight of each group on each specific day as 4 separate line graphs on one axis"*, I assume you want something like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
mydata %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Date, Weight)) + 
  stat_summary(geom = "line", aes(color = Group), fun.y = mean)
```

[image]